# Is it normal for Gulp to include so many node_modules when installing Gulp?

Tags: command-line, npm, gulp

I just installed Gulp with the following commands:

```
npm install --global gulp
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Everything works fine except my node_modules folder is now filled with modules I have never heard of. All the tutorials online about Gulp only show the Gulp module in this folder. For me it's the following:

[node_modules folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCJdg.png)

**Question:**

Is it normal for the node_modules folder to be having these modules?

Thank you in advance

**What tried:**

Updating gulp / node / npm

**Versions:**

gulp -v :

[13:45:13] CLI version 3.9.0

[13:45:13] Local version 3.9.0

npm -v : 3.3.9

node -v : v5.0.0

Comment: Check your `package.json` maybe you have many things already save in your package.json file.

With `npm install --save-dev gulp` my node_modules folder only contain one folder `gulp`.

Comment: Only gulp:
`{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0"
  }
}`

Comment: Maybe try to: create a new folder, init a new npm package file with `npm init` and install gulp in this folder with `npm install --save-dev gulp` maybe the node_modules only contains gulp this time.

Comment: Tried it, still the same.

Comment: Do you try to create the new folder in your harddisk root path `/` or `C:/`?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. I've used gulp on a number of projects and have never seen this before. _Really_ looking fwd to an answer here.

Answer (score 9):

this is due to the maximally flat dependency tree of npm 3. Instead of all the node_modules that gulp requires being installed in a node_modules folder within the gulp dependency, they are all installed in the root node_modules folder.

https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3#npm-v3-dependency-resolution

Comment: And here I thought there was something wrong. While it might not be pretty to look at 100+ folders in node_modules, at least I can rest assured this is completely normal. Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't the designers of npm think to put all the dependencies in a separate folder and keep the root `node_modules` folder for the actual modules that we install.
Having 100+ folders in there makes it hard to find the modules you're working with, quite often I need to open up a module folder to check names of JavaScript modules to import or which stylesheets to reference etc
Seems like bad design to me

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't install all dependencies at the root level. It will install at root level if all other depend on one version. It will install in sub-node-modules directories for conflicting versions. So you have to be careful when adding new modules AFTER initial install. Always be sure `install --save / --save-dev` and `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` again. Otherwise, you might run into surprises next time you install from scratch.